# Radial Coulomb's integral equality

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics, spherical-coordinates

**Introduction**

In quantum mechanics, we have some integrals like this one (spherically symmetric electron-electron electrostatic repulsion):

$$ I = \int_0^{\infty} r^2 R(r)^2 V(r) d r $$

with $R(r)$ the radial electron real wave function with normalization condition:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} r^2 R(r)^2 d r = 1 $$

The potential $V(r)$ is given by:

$$ V(r) = \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r r'^2 R(r')^2 d r' + \int_r^{\infty} r' R(r')^2 d r' $$

So the big integral $I$ is defined as:

$$ I = \int_0^{+ \infty} r^2 R(r)^2 \left( \frac{1}{r} \int_0^r r'^2 R(r')^2 d r' + \int_r^{\infty} r' R(r')^2 d r' \right) d r $$

**Question**

I have found that for certain functions, like $R \propto e^{ - a r}$ ($a > 0$,  parameter), we have:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} r R(r)^2 d r \int_0^r r'^2 R(r')^2 d r' =^? \int_0^{\infty} r^2 R(r)^2 d r \int_r^{\infty} r' R(r')^2 d r'   $$

Does this equality hold for every $R(r)$ (square integrable functions on the unit sphere) ? If yes, how to prove it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Fubini's Theorem. Let me use variables $x,y$ for clarity. Then
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x R(x)^2 dx \int_0^x y^2 R(y)^2 dy
&= \int_0^\infty dx \int_0^x dy\; xy^2 R(x)^2 R(y)^2 \\
&= \int_0^\infty dy \int_y^\infty dx\; xy^2 R(x)^2 R(y)^2 \\
&= \int_0^\infty y^2 R(y)^2 dy \int_y^\infty x R(x)^2 dx,
\end{align*}$$
which is exactly what you want (you can relabel $r=x, r'=y$ in the first integral, $r=y, r'=x$ in the second one). The exchange of integration is justified since $R$ is real and hence everything is positive.

Comment: Thks Tobius. I have just checked out, from line 1 to line 2 you ve just considered:
$ 0 \leq x \leq y < + \infty $ then you exchange the integral using Fubini's theorem $ \int_0^{\infty} d x \int_x^{\infty} d y = \int_0^{\infty} d y \int_0^{y} d x $, if I am not wrong ?

Comment: Yes, precisely!